# Firebase Dynamic link different behaviour in different mobile browsers

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-dynamic-links

```
iOS: 13+ , Swift: 5

FirebaseDynamicLinks (9.2.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
```

I've implemented Firebase DynamicLink feature to my project using default settings in DynamicLink console.

I need to open my iOS App from my website, and on website side I'm creating dynamic link using the REST API provided by the Firebase Document and opening that link by code. this flow works perfect when done in Safari browser but when I do it in Firefox browser it shows error which is too much long that covers whole screen.